# why there is no import of arcade module in vs code for python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, arcade

after run it shows this

```
 "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'arcade'"
```

no arcade found in VS Code for python.

Comment: you need to install `arcade` before you can use/import it.

Comment: Is the module there when you run python from the terminal? If so, make sure the same interpeter is used with vs code

Comment: it is in the extension  and it is already installed but it is not in the ctrl+shift+p cmd. then what to do.

Comment: @Adarsh Sharma -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I successfully installed this module using the [conda environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) of VSCode.

Prerequisite: Install Anaconda outside of VSCode, select this conda environment in VSCode and activate it in the terminal:

[image]

1. Please install the module "`arcade`": (`conda install arcade`)
2. Please install related dependency packages "`geos`" and "`shapely`": (`conda install geos`, `conda install shapely`):
3. Run:

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd and write this:
pip install arcade

after the installation try importing arcade in vs code

vs code uses the same python interpreter as the python terminal